# Android Studio NDK: don't include system header files

Tags: android, android-ndk, include

Android Studio's NDK builder is fetching the wrong header file.

I am using source from a recent revision of `tinyalsa` in my Android application, and when I try to build the project in Android Studio, the NDK builder fetches the header file `pcm.h` from my system at `/usr/include/tinyalsa/pcm.h` instead of the one in my project's source tree.

How can I tell the builder to not look for the file in my system directory? I've already specified an `include` for the intended directory in my `Android.mk`

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Itinyalsa-master/include
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you also need to set the path for the include files - you need to set `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`.

Comment: Thanks. That is a valid flag name. But `LOCAL_CFLAGS` with an `-I` also works. My real problem, it turns out was neglecting that the include path is assumed to begin in the project's `app` directory, so I needed to prefix it with `src/main/...`

Comment: Cool. I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your flag is fine, but the "includes" that you specify are relative to your app's `app` directory.

Change your flag to:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Isrc/main/<intervening-directories>/tinyalsa-master/include
```